# How to trim pairs of value in an array of arrays that match a given scope?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I am working with images with definitions from a dictionary such like this one:
[image: This is what I have]
I want to get rid of those small elements from neighboring entries (top and bot), if they touch the upper or bot boundaries of an image and extend no further than 20 pixels from it (not to include any actual letters touching top or bot), as this image indicates (in red):
[image: This is what I want]

The way I tried doing it was:
 1. Load an image in grayscale
 2. Get contours of the image using `cv2.findContours`
 3. Find contours that begin at x = 0 but end no further than x = 20
 4. Find contours that begin at height-1 and end at height-21
 5. Paint these contours in white

The problem is that `cv2.findContours` returns a list of arrays of arrays of pairs of coordinates. While I was able to delete certain pairs of coordinates, I have difficulty applying that here.

I tried a number of approaches and currently I am stuck with this:

```
import cv2
import os
def def_trimmer(img):
    height, width = img.shape
    img_rev = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_rev,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    # contours = np.concatenate(contours, axis = 0)
    # contours = contours[((contours<[20-1, width])|(contours>[height-20-1, -1])).all(axis=(1,2))]
    for outer in contours:  
        # for outer2 in outer1:
        oldlen = len(outer)
        outer = outer[(((outer<[20-1, width])|(outer>[height-20-1, -1])).all(axis=(1, 2)))]
        newlen = len(outer)
        print((oldlen, newlen))
    cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(255,255,255),-1)
    return(img)
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
img_out = def_trimmer(img)
cv2.imshow("out", img_out)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not necessary to use `findContours` here.

What I would do in your case is to simply iterate over the pixels on the border of your image and remove those components that touch the borders using a growing region algorithm. In more detail:

- Iterate over border pixels until you find a black one.
- Initialize a list to store pixel coordinates.
- Use recursion on neighbouring black pixels to remove them and store their coordinates in the list. If your recursion goes further than 20 pixels away from the border of the image, stop removing pixels and restore the ones you erased before using the stored coordinates in the list.
- Repeat from the beginning until no other border components are left.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That might indeed be faster and easier. I will give it a try soon :)